# Como reduzir o tempo de execução de consulta do MySQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Num banco MySQL 5.6 tenho duas tabelas, TAB_A e TAB_B, cuja relação é de 1 registro em TAB_A para "n" registros em TAB_B. Estou fazendo uma consulta conforme indico abaixo. Quando a tabela TAB_A passa a ter mais do que 10mil registros e a TAB_B passa a ter mais que 200mil registros, a consulta fica bem lenta (demora uns 15 segundos pelo menos). Estou usando nos testes um PC Windows com processador I7 e 8GB de RAM. Não há outros sistemas ocupando memória ou consumindo processamento da CPU.

**PERGUNTA**: Como otimizar essa consulta para obter o mesmo resultado em menos tempo?

Tabela: TAB_A

```
ID | DATAHORA
Onde: 
    ID = index, primary key, inteiro
    DATAHORA: Datetime
```

Tabela TAB_B:

```
ID | ID_TAB_A | REF | VALOR
Onde: 
    ID = index, primary key, inteiro
    ID_TAB_A = index, inteiro
    REF: VARCHAR(100)
    VALOR: VARCHAR(255)
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT    
    TAB_B.REF,
    TAB_B.VALOR,    
    Max(TAB_A.DATAHORA) as DtTime  
FROM    
    TAB_B LEFT JOIN TAB_A 
        ON TAB_A.ID = TAB_B.ID_TAB_A
GROUP BY
    TAB_B.REF  
ORDER BY TAB_B.REF
```

Comment: Já testou criando um índice sobre o campo ID_TAB_A da tabela TAB_B? Já rodou um EXPLAIN?

Comment: O `ID_TAB_A` da tabela TAB_B já tem índice, conforme indicado na linha `ID_TAB_A = index, inteiro`